# Is there a way to have a controller handle route changes internally?

Tags: angularjs

I have a page with several controllers that need to be updated when the route changes.

In one use-case, the route is changed by selecting an item.  I want the controller that handles the select logic to not get reloaded when the route changes.

Instead I just want to manually handle any logic that may need to happen with a route change.

I found this code in another post

```
var lastRoute = $route.current;
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    $route.current = lastRoute;
});
```

But all this does is set the route to the last route.  Not quite what I want.

I played around with the following code, just to see if I can cancel the location change for the controller.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

But this affects all controllers, not just the controller that I have it in.

Is there a way to have a controller handle route changes internally?

Also, I'm aware that I can do this with the search parameters and have the controller not reload on search.  Which is a solution that I'm looking into, but the change affects too many of the other controllers.

Comment: If your view contains multiple controllers, all of those controllers will be affected in one way or another when that view changes. You might want to look into [Angular UI Router nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) as a way to change specific views & controllers on route change